# make an outer a div have a certain height while inner div position changed to fixed

Tags: javascript, css

I have inserted a code to make a div fix to the top of the window when I scroll down a page.
I have inserted this div inside a wrapper div and have set both div's height to 80px;
When I scroll down the page, the inner div position is changed to fixed while the wrapper div is static but after firebugging it I could see that it's height shrank when you inspect it but the height in px didn't change.
How can I make the outer div have the height of 80px stay while it's inner div which has also height of 80px and its position changed to fixed.

For example:

```
<div id="navbarWrapper" style="height:80px;position:static">
         <div id="navbar" style="height:80px">
              <ul><li></li></ul>
         </div>
</div>
```

Now, I have a scroll event which catch scrolls and when it happens I make the #navbar in fixed position and when I inspect the dom I see that the #navbarWrapper shrank and since the #navbar pos changed to fixed, it was took out of the dom element hierarchy in the window and the wrapper div shrank and I would like it to still have the height of 80px although it's empty now.

Thanks,

Comment: What you're describing doesn't make a lot of sense. Perhaps you could prepare a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Pointy, The navbarWrapper shrinks when the inner div position is set to fixed and since in fixed position the element is taken out of the window object the wrapper element is now an empty div element and although it's height is set to 80px; in firebug I could see it's shrank when inspecting it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "shrink" here. It's got a fixed height; it really can't change in size. [Here is a test case](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZXTK/) based on what you have described, and I don't see that behavior.

Comment: @Pointy, my bad, since I'm using the inner div to get top fixed, the other elements scroll up when I scroll down the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fixed the position of a certain **div**, you have to use `position:fixed;` to make the wrapper div fixed. For more perfection you can share the code as well.